# Not able to start multiple threads in my application

Tags: android, multithreading, onclicklistener

I am trying to create a simple wack-a-mole in android. I created an array of buttons. When users clicks "start" I want to start a thread for each button . This thread will toggle the button in on and off state. I coded the application in swing(java) it works well. I am trying the same in android but it is creating problems. Please suggest what is wrong. I am starting a thread for each button but the application terminates. If I just start only one thread for any particular button then it works fine.

EDIT: Even after hard coding the buttons thread it is crashing on the click. Nothing is displayed in the logcat. 
Creating the buttons : all buttons are intialized I am able to click on them and their action perform is working. Code written in oncreate method.

```
int j=0;
        for (int k = 0; k <ROWS; k++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            //inner loop:
            for (int l = 0; l < COLS; l++) {
                btn[j] = new Button(this);
                TableRow.LayoutParams  tr = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layout.setWeightSum(12.0f);
                tr.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
                btn[j].setLayoutParams(tr);

                row.addView(btn[j]);
                j++;
            }
```

EDIT: COde written on onclick() listener of start(some other button from above created buttons) button. If I start only one thread the application works, but crashes if I ret to create mutiple thread. Is it not the correct way of creating thread? I sont think ASYNCTASK is useful here but comments are welcome.

```
start.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            EditText timer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);

            // Called when user clicks the start button
            public void onClick(View v) {

                       Log.i("thread started for ", btn[0]+"");

                        ButtonsThread  bt2 = new ButtonsThread(btn[0]);
                        bt2.start();
                        ButtonsThread  bt3 = new ButtonsThread(btn[1]);
                        bt3.start();
                        ButtonsThread  bt4 = new ButtonsThread(btn[2]);
                        bt4.start();
                        ButtonsThread bt5 = new ButtonsThread(btn[3]);
                        bt5.start();
                        ButtonsThread bt6 = new ButtonsThread(btn[4]);
                        bt6.start(); 
         }});
```

Please suggest why this for loop is crashing the application.

Question 2: When I am creating the buttons in oncreate() method I want to attach a listener to them.
I created a class implementing onClickListener() and attached its object on all the buttons :
// this was the wrong code which I corrected now.

```
for (int k = 1; k < 10; k++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        //innerloop:
        for (int l = 1,j=0; l < 4; j++,l++) {
            btn[j] = new Button(this);

            btn[j].setEnabled(true);
         //listner class
            Score scoreListener = new Score();
            btn[j].setOnClickListener(scoreListener);
            row.addView(btn[j]);
```

this is also causing the application to fail if I click any button. 
This is the code of Thread class:

```
class ButtonsThread extends Thread {
    Button moleButton;

    ButtonsThread(Button b) {

        this.moleButton = b;
        Log.i(TAG,"buttone thread created"+b);
    }
public void run() {
        while (timerInLong > 0) {
               Log.i("while","while loop ");
            try {
                MapLocation.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        moleButton.setEnabled(true);
                        moleButton.setText(":-)");
                    }
                });
                moleButton.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                      
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                        moleButton.setEnabled(true);
                       moleButton.setText(":-)");
                       moleButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                   }
             });

                Thread.sleep(1000);
                moleButton.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        moleButton.setEnabled(false);
                        moleButton.setText(":-(");
                        moleButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                });
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: how many items are in your array {btn}? and post some error logs please..

Comment: I wanted 16 buttons. But any number as of now will work I just want my application to start working. I am stuck at the same place for long time now. The application is not printing any logs for exception in log cat I dont know why @Elltz

Comment: You're not likely to get a solution if you can't say what exception(s) it's throwing, and can't provide a runnable example.

Comment: Question is now messed up with lot of code. I think I should post a new question. I will post a code which you can run. Apologies

Answer (score 1):

You're not consistent in your treatment of how many buttons are in your array:

- In the "working" code you use `btn[0]`.
- In the "problem" loop you use `btn[1]`, `btn[2]`, `btn[3]`, `btn[4]`.
- In the button creation loop you initialize `btn[0]`, `btn[1]`, `btn[2]` only, but you repeatedly reinitialize those elements with 9 different buttons each.

It's hard to make sense of this but it seems you're leaving `btn[3]` and `btn[4]` uninitialized, probably causing a `NullPointerException` when you start using them. (You've neglected to say what exception you're getting...)

Be careful with your loop conditions. Unless you want to treat specially the first element of an array you shouldn't write a loop of the form:

```
for (int k = 1; k < N; k++)
```

Much more often you'd want to start at 0:

```
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
```

or for some uses, start at 1 and use `<=` as the boundary condition:

```
for (int k = 1; k <= N; k++)
```

I can't answer your question 2 because you say you've post the score listener code and you haven't.

Comment: ok thanks got the mistake initializing j=0 everytime. but the problem is still not solved. I will post the code in answer.@Boann